# flask restless unable to construct query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restless

I have two Flask-SQLAlchemy models and the respectives Flask-Restless API endpoints as following:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    document = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(45))

class Student(db.Model):
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.person_id'))
    code = db.Column(db.String(45))

    person = db.relationship('Person', backref=db.backref('students', lazy='dynamic'))

manager.create_api(Person, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
manager.create_api(Student, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

These URLs works fine:

- `http://localhost:8080/api/person`
- `http://localhost:8080/api/student`

But when I try to make search queries to related models as described in the [official docs](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchformat.html#examples), I am getting `{ "message": "Unable to construct query" }` for these requests:

- `http://localhost:8080/api/person?q={"filters":[{"name":"students__code","op":"eq","val":"1"}]}`
- `http://localhost:8080/api/person?q={"filters":[{"name":"students","op":"has","val":{"name":"code","op":"eq","val":"1"}}]}`
- `http://localhost:8080/api/student?q={"filters":[{"name":"person__document","op":"eq","val":"111"}]}`
- `http://localhost:8080/api/student?q={"filters":[{"name":"person","op":"any","val":{"name":"document","op":"eq","val":"111"}}]}`

I am using Flask 0.10.1, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.0, Flask-Restless 0.17.0, SQLAlchemy 1.0.6 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

The numerical values in your queries should not be quoted.

Incorrect:

```
"val":"1"
```

Correct:

```
"val":1
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from [this](https://github.com/jfinkels/flask-restless/issues/122) (see last answer) flask-restless issue:

> According to the warning in [this
>   section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders)
>   of the SQLAlchemy documentation, dynamic relationship can only be used
>   for one-to-many relationships, not many-to-one relationships. In version 0.8.0b2(+), SQLAlchemy raises an exception if you try to use a dynamic relationship loader for the wrong kind of relationship.

And the [warning](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders) reads:

> Warning
>
> The “dynamic” loader applies to collections only. It is not valid to
>   use “dynamic” loaders with many-to-one, one-to-one, or uselist=False
>   relationships. Newer versions of SQLAlchemy emit warnings or
>   exceptions in these cases.

**Update**

You cannot have a many-to-one relationship which is dynamic. Your `person` relationship is - because of `backref` - a many-to-one relationship beside being a one-to-many. From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html):

> To establish a bidirectional relationship in one-to-many, where the
>   “reverse” side is a many to one, specify the backref option.

Comment: According to this, I don't find errors in my models.